# run shell command inside Hive that uses Hive's variables value as input

Tags: variables, hive, emr

I have a python script that receives a Hive table name and 2 dates and adds all partitions between those dates. (runs a bunch of `hive -e 'alter table add partition (date=...)'`)

What i would like to do is when running a Hive script that has a hiveconf:date variable
pass it to the python script as input.

something like:

```
!python addpartitions.py mytable date=${hiveconf:date}
```

but of course the variable substitution does not take place...

Any way to achieve this?